# Strata in Cox regression

Tags: cox-model

I have a Cox regression as below

```
w = coxph(Surv(stag, event) ~ a + b, data = df) # 
summary(w)
```

Where `Pr(>|z|)` of all variables less `0.05`
But when I do

```
w = coxph(Surv(stag, event) ~ a + b + strata(c), data = df) # 
summary(w)
```

`Pr(>|z|)` of `b` = 0.09

What does this mean? Should I exclude `b` from the equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second model compares survival at different values of `b` for fixed values of `c` -- that's what a stratified Cox model does and what the `strata()` specification asks for.

So either the association between `b` and survival is weaker when comparing observations with the same value of `c` (because `c` explains some of that association), or there is just less information about the association for fixed values of `c` (because `b` and `c` are correlated).

If you were in a situation where it made sense to choose variables based just on $p$-values, and you wanted to include `c` in the model, you would exclude `b`. But in most settings it doesn't made sense to choose variables based just on $p$-values.